# How can my Firefox extension download a partially downloaded file?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, download

Mozilla has some [code snippets for downloading files from a Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files).

I didn't see how to finish downloading partially downloaded files similar to `wget -c`.

Is there some way to continue downloading a partially downloaded file from a Firefox extension?

The [documentation for `nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebBrowserPersist#saveURI%28%29) has a parameter `aExtraHeaders`. Do I just use the HTTP header `Range` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nsIWebBrowserPersist` API does not support resuming.

You could try to use the [built-in download manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm). Or at least [the code for it](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/jsdownloads/) might be helpful.

Otherwise, you have to go more low-level than that. In the grand scheme of things, you'll need:

- Use `nsIChannel`/`nsIHttpChannel` directly.
- Construct a channel via [`nsIIOService.newChannel*()`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cf378dddfac8/netwerk/base/public/nsIIOService.idl#l65).
- Try to `QueryInterface` the channel to `nsIHttpChannel`.
- Either use [`nsIHttpChannel.setRequestHeader`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cf378dddfac8/netwerk/protocol/http/nsIHttpChannel.idl#l70), or `QI` again and use [`nsIResumableChannel.resumeAt()`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cf378dddfac8/netwerk/base/public/nsIResumableChannel.idl). The latter requires you to know the the entityID (ETag for http) beforehand, but will take care of a bunch of stuff when used, like verifying the server does actually respond with a ranged response.
- Implement a [`nsIStreamLister`/`nsIRequestObserver`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cf378dddfac8/netwerk/base/public/nsIStreamListener.idl), and call [`channel.asyncOpen(listener, ...)`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cf378dddfac8/netwerk/base/public/nsIChannel.idl#l144) with it.
- In `listener.onStartRequest`, you'll want to double check that the request is good to go (The server actually replied `206`, and so on).
  Also, time to open the file, either via an nsIFileStream or something like OS.File (the latter is preferred these days for snappiness-reasons). See MDN for more info. Don't forget to seek to the appropriate location within the file.
- In `listener.onDataAvailable`, write the data to your file. Also check that the server does not send too much data.
- In `listener.onStopRequest` handle any failure (connection cut, amount transferred). Close your file. Notify the user or whatever.
- You probably need to implement a lot of other stuff e.g. to handle redirects, http-auth, etc.

As you can see, the amount of work you need to do and amount of code you need to write is non-trivial.